# Cross tables - 252 queries - Optimize

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 5 tables in a database:

Products

Applications

Materials

Relation between products and materials ( N: M )

Relation between products and applications ( N: M )

I need to make a table with the relationship between :

```
Application 1 | Material 1 | Total products having application 1 + Material 1
Application 1 | Material 2 | Total products having application 1 + Material 2
Application 1 | Material 3 | Total products having application 1 + Material 3
Application 1 | Material N | Total products having application 1 + Material N

Application 2 | Material 1 | Total products having application 2 + Material 1
Application 2 | Material 2 | Total products having application 2 + Material 2
Application 2 | Material 3 | Total products having application 2 + Material 3
Application 2 | Material N | Total products having application 2 + Material N

Application N | Material 1 | Total products having application N + Material 1
Application N | Material 2 | Total products having application N + Material 2
Application N | Material 3 | Total products having application N + Material 3
Application N | Material N | Total products having application N + Material N
```

I have this SQL that shows me the total perfectly fine.

```
SELECT A.APPLICATION_ID, A.APPLICATION_name_spanish, M.MATERIAL_ID, M.MATERIAL_name_spanish, COUNT(P.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM t_products P
LEFT JOIN t_products_materials PM ON P.PRODUCT_ID=PM.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN t_materials M ON PM.MATERIAL_ID=M.MATERIAL_ID
LEFT JOIN t_products_applications PA ON P.PRODUCT_ID=PA.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN t_applications A ON PA.APPLICATION_ID=A.APPLICATION_ID
GROUP BY A.APPLICATION_ID, M.MATERIAL_ID
ORDER BY A.APPLICATION_ID ASC, M.MATERIAL_ID ASC
```

BUT I do not take those relationships where the crossing Application N + Material N-> Total = 0 PROCUT

How I can get the full list of materials x applications although the outcome of this relationship is zero prductos ?

Here the SQL with tables and content: http://www.javiscript.es/images_foros/sql.sql

Comment: I don't think this makes complete sense on every application to every material.  If some materials are never associated to an application, why have it.  Ex: a car engine (application) has nothing to do with a fabric (material), such as seats, and vice-versa.

Comment: The need for that if they are associated and not associated is because the customer wants to make a table of materials / applications.

With this board wants to see what association has more quantity and go making products associated with other associations.

See this example: http://www.javiscript.es/images_foros/tabla_materiales_aplicaciones.jpg

In blue box need to set total products for material N x Application N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you need to start with the list of all possible pairs of applications and materials.  You get this using a cross join:

```
select a.application_id, a.application_name_spanish, m.material_id, m.material_name_spanish,
       count(pm.product_id)
from t_applications a cross join
     t_materials m left join
     t_products_applications pa
     on pa.application_id = a.application_id left join
     t_products_materials pm
     on pm.product_id = pa.product_id and
        pm.material_id = m.material_id;
group by a.application_id, a.application_name_spanish, m.material_id, m.material_name_spanish,
order by a.application_id, m.material_id;
```

As a note, you don't actually need the fifth table, `t_products`.  You can just use the match to `t_products_materials`, assuming that all your tables have proper foreign key relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But the results of your SQL returns only 1 line.


This is the result:
`application_id----application_name_spanish-----material_id-----material_name_spanish-----count(pm.product_id)


1-----Arquitectura-----25-----Lasermax-----272`

Comment: The new SQL get me a list with all combinatiosn but tue conunt (count(pm.product_id)) on all rows == 0

Comment: @Javichuteck . . . That is not making sense to me, unless the tables are empty.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with some data?

Comment: I got confused. Many of the early records are zero. But then if correct results.
I will review the results manually to see if everything is okay.

Comment: @Javichuteck . . . You can try adding `order by count(pm.product_id) desc` to see if there are any values -- and if they match up with what you expect.

Comment: Everything works fine, and the data is correct. It's just what I need.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Then, I would prequery every combination of materials and applications (alias "AllMatApps").  Since this appears to be a relatively small set, I am also getting the corresponding "name" values for the application and material vs re-joining again after.
A secondary query is the join of ACTUAL materials and applications pre-aggregated.  Then join to AllMatApps

```
    SELECT
          AllMatApps.APPLICATION_ID, 
          AllMatApps.APPLICATION_name_spanish, 
          AllMatApps.MATERIAL_ID, 
          AllMatApps.MATERIAL_name_spanish, 
          COALESCE( SUM( PMPA.PMPACount ), 0) as FinalCount
       from 
          ( SELECT 
                a.Application_ID,
                a.name_spanish,
                m.Material_ID,
                m.name_spanish
             from
                t_applications a 
                   cross join t_materials m ) AllMatApps
          LEFT JOIN
          ( select
                  PA.Application_ID,
                  PM.Material_ID,
                  COUNT(*) as PMPACount
               from
                  t_products_materials PM
                     JOIN t_products_applications PA
                        ON PM.PRODUCT_ID = PA.PRODUCT_ID
               group by
                  PA.Application_ID,
                  PM.Material_ID ) PMPA
             ON AllMatApps.Application_ID = PMPA.Application_ID
            AND AllMatApps.Material_ID = PMPA.Material_ID
   order by 
      AllMatApps.APPLICATION_ID, 
      AllMatApps.MATERIAL_ID
```

Comment: This query works fine, but I think subqueries is not necessary.

In the example below, Gordon Linoff not use subqueries and get the same result, more optimized.
Also, thanks @Drapp